# Access data from jQueryUI dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to access the form values in a jQueryUI dialog box from outside the box?

Answer (score 2):

If you have given an ID to the dialog box then you could have access to the form with

```
$('#dialogID form')
```

or if you can give an id to the form and access it like normal..

```
$('#formID')
```

Comment: Is it possible to append the values from this form to the values of another form on the original page when the form on the original page is submitted?

Comment: @Brian, depends on how this form is created... if it is only alive while the dialog is open then no you cannot directly access its values from the rest of the code.. If ,on the other hand, the dialog is kept alive then yes, you can retrieve the data..

Comment: you could put the elements of this popup-form inside the other one then wrap them with a div, and then create the dialog out of this wrapper div. this way the form elements will already be inside the form, but will only appear in the dialog box..